# My first SPFx hello world - How do I get site owner?

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, modern-experience, 2019, spfx-extensions

I'm new here and looking for some guidance if possible. I have been following the hello world MS SPFx framework walkthrough. I have been playing the page placeholder walkthrough to add a custom footer to SharePoint 2019 on prem.

However I wanted to add one extra thing and well. I'm stuck. I'm trying to put the Title in a variable or string so I can use it further down in my code. I just can't get it to work

The complete page with the edits from your help

```
export default class HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer
  extends BaseApplicationCustomizer<IHelloWorldApplicationCustomizerProperties> {
    private _topPlaceholder: PlaceholderContent | undefined;
    private _bottomPlaceholder: PlaceholderContent | undefined;

  @override
  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `Initialized ${strings.Title}`);

    // Wait for the placeholders to be created (or handle them being changed) and then
    // render.
    this.context.placeholderProvider.changedEvent.add(this, this._renderPlaceHolders);

    return Promise.resolve<void>();

  }

private siteOwner: string = "";

private _renderPlaceHolders(): void {
    console.log("HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer._renderPlaceHolders()");
    console.log(
      "Available placeholders: ",
      this.context.placeholderProvider.placeholderNames
        .map(name => PlaceholderName[name])
        .join(", ")
    );

    // Pull user groups

this.context.spHttpClient.get(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/site/owner`,  
          SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)  
          .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {  
            response.json().then((responseJSON: any) => {  
              console.log(responseJSON.Title); 
              this.siteOwner = responseJSON.Title;
            });  
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Open the `./src/extensions/helloWorld/HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer.ts` file
2. Add private property to class like:

```
private siteOwner: string = "";
```

3. Inside API call response, set its value to site owner name:

```
this.stringOwner = responseJSON.Title;
```

4. Then you can use this class property (`this.stringOwner`) anywhere inside the class to access the site owner name.

---

Also check below SPFx extension samples to see how others in community are using SPFx extensions:

[SPFx extension samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples)

---

**Update from comments**:

Update your `_renderPlaceHolders()` method like below:

```
private async _renderPlaceHolders() {
    console.log("HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer._renderPlaceHolders()");
    console.log(
      "Available placeholders: ",
      this.context.placeholderProvider.placeholderNames
        .map(name => PlaceholderName[name])
        .join(", ")
    );

    // Pull site owner
    const response = await this.context.spHttpClient.get(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/site/owner`, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1);
    
    const userData: any = await response.json();
    this.siteOwner = userData ? userData.Title : "";

    console.log(this.siteOwner);
}
```

Comment: Omg almost there.. I have added it and now the result has gone from undefined to empty. But the console still writes out the correct data.. I have no errors in Vscode??

Comment: Where are you getting empty result? You should call above api in `onInit` method. Also, you can make it sync call so that you will get site owner name in class property before everything else in class executes.

Comment: So now the API call looks like this

 this.context.spHttpClient.get(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/site/owner`,  
          SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)  
          .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {  
            response.json().then((responseJSON: any) => {  
              console.log(responseJSON.Title); 
              this.siteOwner = responseJSON.Title;
            });  
          });

Comment: Can you please edit your existing question & add complete code inside your class ? That will help to answer your question more precisely.

Comment: I'm struggling to paste the code wthout all the extra rendering. Ill try to cut that out and then paste

Comment: Ok pasted code.. just not as neat as i want it. Not sure how that works so sorry for the messy read..

Comment: Check updated answer. I have tested it on my end & working fine. it should work for you.

Comment: Thats it... IT Worked

Comment: Was hoping maybe you guys can answer my other question below https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/295283/cors-and-sp2019-on-prem-dev