# CORS and SP2019 on prem dev

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx-extensions, cors

I'm again trying my hands on some SPFx development on code downloaded from GitHub. As we are behind firewalls and they won't open anything I have to use a local CDN for all my manifest files and what not.
Now some of the small devs i have done work fine but some of them i run into the CORS issue with the error below

[image]

Now one of the dev's that i played with i did get to works with the below code as i did get some great help from this community

[image]

However when i try to do this on this latest dev below I can't get it to work. Below is the full ts file and i just tried to enter the same code.

[image]

I'm a inhouse guy who got thrown into this because I like to tinker but I'm now in way over my head. If anyone has some time to help it would be great. The code that I started with for CORS is [here](https://tahoeninjas.blog/2019/02/05/getting-around-cors-issues-in-spfx-with-sphttpclient/)

Comment: The actual problem is that the solution is not allowed to reach the files in the CDN folder (Due to the CORS issue). All permissions are set correctly and the below code works and the solution can access the files in the local CDN.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293065/my-first-spfx-hello-world-how-do-i-get-site-owner

Comment: Just wondering if anyone had any ideas??